# What is the meaning of exception message NoSuchMethodException:MyClass.<init> (AnotherClass)?

Tags: java, classloader, nosuchmethoderror

What is the meaning of an exception message like follows:

```
Failed to instantiate [ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext]
Reported exception:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.red5.logging.LoggingContextSelector.<init>(ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext)
```

I.e. on what stage of the process what was failed?

Answer (score 0):

Without looking too much into it I would assume that LoggerContext's constructor is calling a method in LogginContextSelector that doesn't exist. This would most likely be due to missing an import or attempting to instantiate LoggerContext improperly.

Would you mind giving a snippet of your code where you instantiate LoggerContext as well as what library you are working with?

Answer (score 0):

A log referring a <init> method represents the instantiations of a class, in this case LoggingContextSelector. The problem here seems to be a dependencies conflict regarding it's versions.

To me sounds like you need to use a different version of org.red5.logging.LoggingContextSelector.